# Difficulties to query nested arrays with multiple itens Mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongoose, nested, find

I`ve modeled a document to be:

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, max: 50, unique: true },
    email: {type: String, required: true, max: 50, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, max: 20},
    monitoringProject: [
        {
            projectName: { type: String, required: true, max: 30},
            token: { type: String, required: true},
            dispositives: [
                {
                    name: { type: String, required: true, max: 15},
                    value: { type: String, required: true},
                    token: { type: String}
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    controlProject: [
        {
            projectName: { type: String, required: true, max: 30},
            token: { type: String, required: true},
            dispositives: [
                {
                    name: { type: String, required: true, max: 15},
                    value: { type: String, required: true},
                    token: { type: String}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

In the monitoringProject, for example, I can log too many different projects, and, to each project, I can log too many dispositives. So, I have nested arrays. In other project, where I have just one project, and many dispositives, I can list them and search for just one dispositive. But in this case, like this:

```
[ { "_id": "5ee18ece1ea5af75bae55f91", "monitoringProject": [ { "dispositives": [ { "_id": "5ee18ef31ea5af75bae55f9c", "name": "Dispositivo 1", "token": "$2b$15$NntmY9ihNZ7R1Vg1WMtmzOSjlfCoKIuHLofF6g5tKXA57WLLc2At2" }, { "_id": "5ee18ef81ea5af75bae55f9e", "name": "Dispositivo 2", "token": "$2b$15$OZB7HbDLvonsv6A71ozW7.yVY2vJOipTCj0AH7XzoafQwwDho.jpm" }, { "_id": "5ee18efc1ea5af75bae55fa0", "name": "Dispositivo 3", "token": "$2b$15$0hpDzNeTO2qJzBVyAHc/UesrnIRi/YpeAlpCLewNhmfl6fe3SEN0i" }, { "_id": "5ee2278d0754817853134bf3", "name": "Dispositivo 4", "token": "$2b$15$ldC5/CyxITPJGUvtXJ.2S.D6a3FBftg6ctQeS4ne/9xpMP5PPiszK" }, { "_id": "5ee2288956fc4c7870044395", "name": "Dispositivo 6", "token": "$2b$15$3rJt.gXEi/gALvrwxVUsWuwF2RUcBmZcoFOQeXwF45ZuKQrB3AGHG" }, { "_id": "5ee6d23d1756b7a8384bcff0", "name": "Dispositivo 7", "token": "$2b$15$C3I9STKJpf9i/7hzhvHEs.IizXpOEmgRTD3hd7ZSdcvATb73Z0zNC" } ], "_id": "5ee18ede1ea5af75bae55f94", "projectName": "Projeto 2", "token": "$2b$15$xaytMbMnGd3BMAGapX8nn.imvkQKetqx0OIlUUyP3gCxlKz/G6DiG" } ] } ]
```

I can only list all the Dispositives. I want to return just, for example, "Dispositivo 2".

I used to querys:

```
await User.find({ email: req.body.email, monitoringProject: { $elemMatch: { token: req.body.projecttoken, dispositives: { $elemMatch: { token: req.body.dispositivetoken } } } } }, { "monitoringProject.$.dispositives": 1} )
```

or

```
await User.find({ email: req.body.email, 'monitoringProject.token': req.body.projecttoken, 'monitoringProject.dispositives.token': req.body.dispositivetoken}, { 'monitoringProject.dispositives.$': 1 })
```

Using find or findOne. How can I return just the document I want? I tried so many different ways, but with no lucky.